# C# plugin for authoring DVD movies?

Tags: c#, dvd-burning, mpeg, vob

We have a product which includes some video editing tools. We've had a request to add the ability to write the resulting videos to a standard DVD movie disk.

To do this, I estimate I'd have to create mpg files, covert to vobs, write the correct directory structure and inf files etc. A lot of work.

Is there some .Net sdk library for doing this? Open-source is ideal, but commercial is ok too.

I've found articles discussing the different subtasks of the problem;

- [How to burn video DVD from c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441227/how-to-burn-video-dvd-from-c)
- http://standardmpeg.com/documentation/tutorials/csharp
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/bwgburn/

but nothing which offers a complete solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [DVDBuilder](http://www.dvdbuilder.com) is what you looking for. I never used it but after reading your question, and hopfully understanding it, I think this could be the solution.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, that is what I used in the end, in combination with a few other tricks. The end solution was quite complex - enough for a blog entry if I have time.